# Structural equation modelling problem

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I am working on my thesis and I had to analyse my likert scale data. So I hired a freelancer and I am confused with the results he gave me.... he performed SEM in spss instead of AMOS and gave me reference for the same... my now my concern is that instead of giving model fit values he gave me R value... now I really doubt if it really is SEM or something else [image]

Comment: You can't do structural equation models in SPSS. AMOS is the SPSS SEM package.  The analysis you show is a a regression analysis. In addition, I would as for a refund.  "A value of R-square more than 0.10 is acceptable" is like saying "A piece of string longer than 2 feet is good enough." It depends what you want to do with the piece of string.

Comment: "ANOVA table represents whether there is a factually huge distincition between group means" sounds like someone took some random words and threw them together.

Comment: "Values of VIF should always be greater than 1". That is dead right, because VIF = 1 - R^2. R^2 can't be less than zero, so if VIF is less than 1, there's an error in the software you're using.

Comment: I could go on ...

Comment: so u mean this is not SEM and I am doomed now @JeremyMiles.... since I have only 10 days left in my thesis submission... I was deceived by two freelancers after I paid them,,, and now I have no option... would u suggest me a mathematical model that I can do on my ordinal data.

Comment: This is not what is usually called SEM. I don't know if that means you are doomed.

Comment: Perhaps the regression will be sufficient for your thesis?

Comment: he first had done PCA and derived latent factors and then this regression analysis......and called the whole procedure as SEM.... But I couldn't digest it... anyways .. seems regression is the only option I am left with now @JeremyMiles

Comment: What does your advisor say about this?

Comment: had he been of any use... I wouldn't have end up wasting so much money and time and energy..... I am basically doing M.tech in transportation engineering,, so statistics is out of league